# Почему возникает проблема тупиков, если есть примитивы синхронизации?

Tags: c, алгоритм, синхронизация, mutex, семафоры

У нас есть условия возникновения тупиков. Один из них - Условие взаимоисключения (Mutual exclusion). Одновременно использовать ресурс может только один процесс.
Этот примитив синхронизации нужен был затем, чтобы ,например, исключить ситуацию гонок. Как тут может возникнуть тупиковая ситуация?

Потом, если мы рассматриваем принтер, то говорим о ситуации , когда два процесса хотят что-то напечатать, и чтобы не было в итоге "каши", мы используем примитив синхронизации.
Но теперь зачем-то отказываются от примитивов синхронизации в пользу спулинга, который должен разрешить ситуацию той же каши и монопольного захвата устройства.
Или примитивы синхронизации(взаимоисключение) могут дать "засидеться" одному процессу с разделяемым устройством слишком долго? Но есть же планировщик и данный процессу квант времени(например RR-4).

Comment: *`"Как тут может возникнуть тупиковая ситуация?"`* -- процесс 1: `lock(A); ...  lock(B)`, а процесс 2 в то же время: `lock(B); ... lock(A);`

Comment: @Elvin *Почему возникает проблема тупиков, если есть примитивы синхронизации?* - у меня есть очень похожий вопрос: "Почему люди гибнут в авариях, если есть ПДД?".

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xHCzk.jpg